# I am trying to insert values from a one dimension array to a 2d matrix in php, getting Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, matrix

I have an array

```
$re_arr=array("ask","bat","cod","dig","egg","fur","gap","hay","ice","jar","kin","lee","mux","nod","odd","pro","qat","raw","sad","tax","ups","vet","wed","xis","yak");
```

it has 25 elements, i want to transfer its elements one by one into a 2d matrix. 
i am trying using:

```
  echo"<table border=”1px” width=30% height=50% align=center>";
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
        echo"<tr>";
      for($j=0;$j<5;$j++)
      {
        for($k=0;$k<25;$k++)
        $mat[$i][$j]=$re_arr[$k];
        echo "<td>$mat[$i][$j]</td>"; 
      }
      echo"</tr>";
    }


    }
```

$i and $j are for iteration in $mat which is a 2d matrix and $k is to go through all the 25 elements of the single dimension array .

output is:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\authen.php on line 4

and the table shown in the picture, I want the elements inside $re_arr to be displayed instead.
[image: output of the code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some mistake logic in iteration you don't need to iterate over 25 elem arrays:

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1px" width=30% height=50% align=center>';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        $mat[$i][$j] = $re_arr[$i * 5 + $j];
        echo "<td>{$mat[$i][$j]}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: please can you explain the logic of  $re_arr[$i * 5 + $j]. can i do it like $re_arr[$k++]  where $k is initialized to 0

Comment: @AzraMahrukh when you additionally iterate over array all you elements will be set to $re_arr[25], because $k going from 0 to 25 for each $i and $j.

Comment: yes i got that. Thank you for the reply. useful.
 I instead just took a variable initialized to 0 and just incremented it used it as index in $re_arr instead of using $i * 5 + $j as index. It solved the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Please write the array not in the string area:

```
echo "<td>" . $mat[$i][$j] . "</td>";
```

Or use this:

```
echo "<td>{$mat[$i][$j]}</td>";
```

This should solve the problem with the notice.

Comment: @JohnConde: He wrote about an error message "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\authen.php on line 4".

Comment: Because the PHP parser founds the [-character as invalid in a variable. The parsing process is stopped there.

Comment: @Richard Reiber it solved the problem partially.no Notice but the output is showing just one words in all 25 cell in the table. i can understand its because of this code "for($k=0;$k<25;$k++)
       i want the 25 elements of string to get distributed in the 2d matrix.